# Slowing down a motor - Mousebot

Tags: motor, speed

I put together the a Herbie the [Mousebot](http://www.solarbotics.com/products/k%5Fhm/) the other day and he is FAST!  Too fast to demonstrate in a small area.

Have a look a this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVaVRlmiQUs&feature=player%5Fembedded) to see just how he zips around.

Documentation: [Mousebot](http://www.solarbotics.com/assets/documentation/khm%5Fherbie%5Fthe%5Fmousebot%5Fmanual.pdf)

So my question is - how should i go about slowing him down a bit - so i can demonstrate it in a 1m x 1m area.

Cheers,

Mad_z

Comment: I helped my mate make a couple of these for a university project, wow those things are crazy! I just remember having loads of hassle trying to glue a lever onto a micro switch at the front (so it turns around when it hits a wall). I think he'd bought the basic kit, so we were building them into old computer mouses. I think they're a fantastic starter robot kit!

Comment: It would be groovy to design an evasive robot with a bright light on for the mousebot to chase after!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd imagine a resistor on the positive connection to the motors would do the trick. You will probably need to experiment with the value to get it right.

Comment: Yes, this does work; I'm using this in one of my robots and it works beautifully. Get a high-turn 10k potentiometer, and you can find the value you need pretty easily.

Comment: That's cool, you could get a stereo potentiometer, then you could adjust the top speed of both the motors with one knob, then you could change the speed for different applications/demonstrations.

Answer (score 2):

Decreasing the voltage going into the motor will cause it to go slower. As Jim said putting a resistor just before going into the motor is an excellent way but you will need to switch resistors each time you want to speed back up. Better then using just a regular resistor you may try a potentiometer which is a variable resistor. You use it the same way but you can turn the potentiometers up or down to give more speed or less